# Command to reset NVRAM?

Tags: boot, uefi, bootloader

I'd like to test cloning an image and it looks like when ubuntu starts up on my intel NUC for the first time it will set the nvram to use the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi boot loader. I'd like to unset this if possible to test and verify and was wondering if there is a command that can be used to unset NVRAM to its defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`efibootmgr`  is  a  userspace  application  used  to  modify  the  Intel
       Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) Boot Manager.  This application can
       create and destroy boot entries, change the boot order, change the next
       running boot option, and more.

It is [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=efibootmgr&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

You can check to see if it's installed with `which efibootmgr` which on my system returns:

`/bin/efibootmgr`

`sudo efibootmgr` will list the current entries.

You should get results similar to this:

```
 BootCurrent: 0004
       BootNext: 0003
       BootOrder: 0004,0000,0001,0002,0003
       Timeout: 30 seconds
       Boot0000* Diskette Drive(device:0)
       Boot0001* CD-ROM Drive(device:FF)
       Boot0002* Hard Drive(Device:80)/HD(Part1,Sig00112233)
       Boot0003* PXE Boot: MAC(00D0B7C15D91)
       Boot0004* Linux
```

You can modify your non-default boot entries with the -b switch and delete them with the -B switch.

Assuming the output above, `efibootmgr -b 4 -B` could be
       called to delete entry 4 and remove it from the BootOrder.
Of course you'll have to adjust accordingly for your circumstances.

For more detail on efibootmgr see the [man page.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/efibootmgr.8.html)