# Grub menu items remain after several disk formats

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I've re-installed my OSes several times: from linux to windows, and back. And **I've completely formatted the hard drive too** during a process of installation: deleted all partitions, created a new one, installed an OS to it.

Nonetheless, the grub or grub2 menu items of the old Windows and Arch Linux installations, that were once installed, remain. No matter what. After each new installation they'll remain.

[boot menu items remain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrTpS.jpg)

Why? How to erase them completely?

Comment: Uefi?  `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` please.

Comment: @nobody I'll have  to install an OS first

Comment: then install a OS. For a long shot https://askubuntu.com/questions/893421/command-to-reset-nvram

Comment: @nobody I have no OS installed. When I'm booting from a stick drive with Linux, the `/sys/firmware/efi ` path exists. But it may be that it exists only on that stick drive. However, my Laptop Lenovo Carbon X1 also supports EUFI and BIOS -- both. My question remains -- how to remove all those old boot menu item records? Without an OS installed

Comment: `sudo efibootmgr` from a live-session please.